# CMS WYSIWYG editor When I try to upload an image via WYSIWYG editor it automatically logs out from the admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9

CMS page WYSIWYG editor. When I try to upload an image via WYSIWYG editor, it automatically logs out from the admin panel

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with permissions in your server. Please put the pre-conditions of your development. This can happen by a number of reasons, but your questions are vague.

Comment: My question is clear. i can't upload image using editor logout when click on upload button

Comment: When you can't upload an image, a log should be updated, check the logs on your server first. This is not as simple as it sounds friend @SantoshDhaduk